# Guarantee that an abstract java method calls a specific private method

Tags: java, abstract-class, assert

Thanks in advance for the help.

I am building a library and would like to do the following.  I have an abstract class that users of my library must extend in order to use many of the libraries features.  Within this abstract class I have an abstract method.  Within this abstract method there is a piece of code that must be executed at some point, it does not matter when, as long as it runs each time this particular abstract method is called.  In this code, an array of objects is incrementally updated (this does not matter for my question, I just want to be clear what the code that needs to be executed does).

One potential solution could be to used overloading (ie, explicitly define the method instead of making it abstract).  However, this only works if the user of my library calls the super method.  In addition, taking this approach does not force the user to specifically define this method, as is the entire point of making this method abstract in the first place.

Is there someway to assert that this piece of code (which I would like to run with a private method call for code reuse) runs within this method or must I come up with another solution (ie instead of running this code within the abstract method, call the abstract method within a fully defined function containing this code)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
public abstract class Super{
    public final void doThing(){
        setup();

        // Do everything else
    }

    public abastract void setup();
}

public class Child extends Super{

    // Child class must implement setup()

}
```

Comment: That was what I was thinking too, but I would have to change code that previously called setup() to call doThing().  While this isn't a big deal, I would rather not have to change method names (I want to change existing code as little as possible, including how things are named).  This is why I asked about using an assert and whether there was a way to use one here to get the desired affect somehow.

Comment: You might want to update your question with qualifications like 'the name of the method can't change' etc.

Comment: I know that I can change the method names and do as you have suggested, "ie instead of running this code within the abstract method, call the abstract method within a fully defined function containing this code".  My question is whether there is a way to use an assert statement to get the same desired affect.

Comment: assert statements probably aren't the best idea because they will be optimized out when you run in production. You could assert on your own by setting some state field and then checking that state at the start of every other method in the class.

Comment: That's a very good point.  I'm probably stuck moving stuff around and renaming then.

Comment: BTW, what you have is called 'template method' design pattern.